# "НЕ" или "НИ"?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

Правильно писать "что бы я ни делал...". Почему здесь употребляется частица "ни", а не "не"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Частица НИ в данном случае (в придаточном предложении со значением уступки) усиливает утверждение. Проверим: я делал? - Да. - Пишу "НИ".
я делал? - Нет. _ Пишу "Не". НАпример, *чтобы я этого не делал, меня оставили дома.*
*Что бы я ни делал, все напрасно.*

Comment: В известной песне Пугачева четко пропевала: "Позови меня с собой, что бы путь мне НЕ пророчил", а нужно  - НИ.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь не отрицание, а усиление, поэтому НИ.
Речь о том, что говорящий ("Я") на самом деле всё подразумевающееся именно делал.
"Не" было бы, наример, в случае "Нет такой работы, что бы (которую бы) я не делал".